# Thank God it's Friday, tomorrow is THE weekend. Why the definite article?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, definite-articles, time, zero-article

> Today is Friday. Tomorrow is *the* weekend.

In terms of grammar, how is the definite article justified there?

We say:

> - It's noon.
> - It's 12 o'clock.
> - It's August.
> - It's 2019.

But we also say:

> - It's *the* 23<sup>rd</sup> of the month.
> - It's *the* 21<sup>st</sup> century.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_(grammar)#Definite_article):

> The definite article is used to refer to a particular member of a group or class. It may be something that the speaker has already mentioned or it may be something uniquely specified.

This explains *the* day of the month and *the* number century. Yet today is Friday — no article. Just any old Friday. But tomorrow is *the* weekend — definite article. Though also just any old weekend. So **why “the”?**

Comment: This week has only one end, which is *the* end of this week. It's uniquely specified, because you've anchored it with "tomorrow".

Comment: May be wrong but this my rationale : I think it like a rule "_Saturday_" already somehow implies a "_the_", "_the day of Saturn_". Also as all proper nouns (with a capital letter), you don't use "the". You usual say : "_I know John Hennig_", not "_I know the John Hennig_". or _"Let's ask on Stack Overflow_". Not "_let's ask on the Stack Overflow_" (even though there are only one). For numbers it's a specific rule as well : you use _the_ before ordinals like _12th_, not cardinal numbers like _12_. All other unique cases should use "the".

Comment: @JohnHennig Yep, also it's working for capitalized events like : it's New Year, it's Christmas, it's Shabat, but : it's _the_ birthday of Pacopaco

Comment: However this explanation doesn't explain why we say it's noon, it's midnight, but it's _the_ afternoon, it's _the_ night. I think I'll write Noon and Midnight from now on :D

Comment: ' . . . tomorrow is _the end of the week_ . . .' Therefore it is _the_ week-end.

Comment: @JohnHennig One could say 'at week's end'. And 'at night's middle'. And 'at New Year's Eve'.

Comment: Compare: "It happens on a Monday," "I'll arrive on the Monday before Thanksgiving." "I really need a weekend."

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin It seems that English doesn't have a rule to follow.Even native speakers differ in  many  grammatical aspects

Comment: For all examples I can think of, 'the' is used for time spans, and not used for specific points. This shows why 'the noon' is weird, but 'the afternoon' is fine. There may be counterexamples I'm missing, though. Only for common nouns, of course, as shown by Pacopaco.

Comment: Because we're American, not British.

Answer (score 12):

#### *Weekend* is Just Another *End*

While *weekend* may be a time expression, it is relatively new to the language. Until Saturday became only a half day of work in England’s industrial North, there was no need — a worker’s free time was Sunday, and that was it:

> In Staffordshire, if a person leaves home at the end of his week’s work on the Saturday afternoon to spend the evening of Saturday and the following Sunday with friends at a distance, he is said to be spending his [*week-end*](https://archive.org/details/notesqueries512unse/page/n6?q=%22Staffordshire+if+a+person%22) at So-and-so. — *Notes and Queries*, Fifth series, vol. 12, July–Dec. 1879.

As a compound noun of recent provenance, then, it shouldn’t be surprising that  *weekend* behaves in some syntactical contexts as its final element, i.e., when and where it requires the definite article:

In British English:

> Great business plans begin at [*the end*](https://books.google.de/books?id=r8oaBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&dq=%22at+the+end%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjN6I2L25jkAhUQyaQKHYKZBzg4FBDoATAFegQIARAk). — Summary of David Lavinsky, *Start at the End*, 2012, 2014.
>
> If I'm offered a job on Friday, we can make plans at [*the weekend*](https://books.google.de/books?id=ULb8ouVPJn4C&pg=PA33&dq=%22plans+at+the+weekend%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjPgrTa3JjkAhVIDOwKHYVcB-cQ6AEIPjAD).  — Ruth Dudley Edwards,  *The English School of Murder*, 2000.

In American English:

> And like their neighbors, they had a long gray wooden pier with a small seating area with a tin roof on [*the end*](https://books.google.de/books?id=M33V5-EQlAoC&pg=PA10&dq=%22roof+on+the+end%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir7PKJ55jkAhUJZlAKHaM5DswQ6AEITDAG).  — Fannie Flagg,  *The All-Girl Filling Station's Last Reunion*, 2013,10.
>
> The seed for Disneyland was planted when Walt would take his daughters, Sharon and Diane, to an amusement park or to Santa Monica Pier on [*the weekend*](https://books.google.de/books?id=yB-EDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT40&dq=%22pier+on+the+weekend%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTz9bd5pjkAhVGJFAKHaGpAxMQ6AEILjAB). — Keith Abraham,   *It Starts with Passion: Do What You Love and Love What You Do*, 2019.

In all flavors of English with *until*:

> As they fight for their lives and race for their freedom, they'll discover that what they truly need in order to survive until [*the end*](https://books.google.de/books?id=HJ4uDwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22until+the+end%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjunuPg3pjkAhUSKuwKHfM0CGA4ChDoATACegQIARAQ). — Tracy Ward, *Until the End*, 2013.
>
> Headline: Belgian heatwave: Thalys train service disrupted until [*the weekend*](https://www.brusselstimes.com/all-news/belgium-all-news/61467/heatwave-thalys-train-service-disrupted-until-the-weekend/). — *Brussels Times*, 26 July 2019.

And *during*:

> The background music during [*the end*](http://worldofprankcalls.com/2019/03/29/world-of-prank-calls-episode-29-eminent-domain/) is Mind Over Matter by Dottie from the Pee Wee movie. I'm too lazy to look up her name. — World of Prank Calls, 24 Mar. 2019.
>
> The music during [*the weekend*](http://bluesdanceworld.com/2013/11/21/event-review-rose-city-blues-2013/) was spectacular. — Event Review: Rose City Blues 2013, Blues Dance World, 21 Nov. 2013.

As subject:

> I'm currently 2nd... [*The end*](https://www.pictame.com/media/2058922164875505640_2294118224) will be exciting! — Pictame.com, 6 April 2019.
>
> So while [*the weekend*](https://mjwarriors.ca/prospect-camp-weekend-has-arrived/) will be exciting for the players, it can also be an exciting glimpse into the future for the organization. — Prospect Camp Weekend Has Arrived – Moose Jaw Warriors, 23 May, 2013.

As object:

> If the world should stop revolving, spinning slowly down to die,
>   I’d spend [*the end*](https://www.songfacts.com/lyrics/bread/if) with you. — David Gates, “If,” 1971.
>
> She wasn’t content to spend [*the weekend*](http://worldofprankcalls.com/2019/03/29/world-of-prank-calls-episode-29-eminent-domain/) with the most eligible hunk in the western hemisphere.  — Rita Clay Estrada,  *One Wild Weekend*, 1999, 98.

#### Adverbial, Attributive Use

When used adverbially with a demonstrative or temporals like *next* or *last*, *weekend* behaves like a month:

> *next/last/this August*
>   *next/last/this weekend*

Just as you can’t say

> *We’re planning a trip to Iceland *June (*this/for/in June*)

you can’t say

> We’re planning a trip to the countryside **weekend*.

And you’re back to the prepositions above.

Except *today, yesterday* and *tomorrow*, which require a possessive (*tomorrow’s flight*), and those that take a *-long* compound (day, month, year) *weekend* can be used attributively as other time expressions:

> We’re planning a *Sunday/morning/July/weekend* trip.

Comment: You claim that *weekend behaves like a month* but it also works that way with the day of the week, holiday, season and  year. Next/last/this **Monday/week/summer/Christmas/year**.  We just normally avoid the definite article with the determiner "this" and the adjectives/adverbs (I don't know which)  "next" and "last"

Comment: @Mari-LouA: What I was aiming for was that neither a month nor weekend can be used absolutely, unlike weekdays or holidays, so it was just economical to compare the two.

Comment: @John Hennig: I got a hit from an Indian author and one from from another source that considers "it's weekend" common. I've never heard it myself.

Answer (score 9):

We also say, "Today is *the* 23rd of August," and then we turn around and say, "Today is August 23rd," sans "the," but I digress.

For whatever reason, indicating time has its own set of grammatical rules in English, in all the romance languages, as well.  What I would surmise, though, is that "noon" and "midnight" are nouncount nouns, which we treat as singular for verb conjugation but plural when it comes to articles, thus no "the," whereas words like "weekend" and "month" are not noncount nouns.  The fact that they are not nouncount nouns but count nouns is why the article "the" is justified beforehand.  This even explains why "the" is used in "Today is the 23rd of August" but not in "Today is August 23rd," being that the former implies the count noun "day" after "23rd" but the latter makes no such implication but is the actual proper name of the day.

Comment: "Today is August 23rd" sounds specifically American English to me, I think I would always say "Today is August the 23rd"

Comment: Can you explain "plural when it comes to articles, thus no "the,""? The plural definite article is still _the_, as in _the houses_. It's the indefinite article that becomes a zero article in the plural.

Comment: In some instances we use it, but we often eliminate it.  We can, for example, say, "Give people a chance," but we can't say, "Give person a chance."  In the latter, an article is required.